# Getting the Host name of a Local IP address (java)

Tags: java, network-programming, ip-address, hostname

I use this method in a loop to get the host name of 4 terminal in my local network identified by the ip address *terminal[i].getIp()* .

```
try {
 // Get hostname by textual representation of IP address
 InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(terminal[i].getIp());

 // Get the host name
 String hostname = addr.getHostName();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
}
```

the problem here its that code take so long to return the result (up to 5 seconds)
I wonder if there is another **more optimized** method.

Answer (score 0):

Try the library from Google Guava, I think there are more optimized

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.html

Comment: But there no such method **getHostName()** to print the host name of an ip address.

Comment: There is a method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName() in Inetaddress

Comment: So you could do something line new InewAddresses().forString(ip_address).getHostName()

Comment: thank u for ur ansewer, yes, this is the method which i used in my example **InetAddress.getByName(ip_address).getHostName()** but it take so long to return a result and in most case it return a textual representation of the ip address, and that is not what i want to have.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you didn't use Guava.